# RangeSelector for highstock throws warning for "year" type

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I am new to Highstock and customized my date and range selector.Everything is working fine except for the fact that the following code when added throws a warning on Console. Is anyone else facing the same issue?

<RangeSelector.Button count={1} type="year" offsetMin={0} offsetMax={0}>Last 12 months</RangeSelector.Button>

**Warning message**

​
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `type` of value `year` supplied to `RangeSelectorButton`, expected one of ["millisecond","second","minute","hour","day","week","month","ytd","all"].

Comment: Why don't you try using one of the expected arguments like "ytd" instead of year?

Comment: Thanks Dominik! But "ytd" would display one full year range starting from a certain date and not last one year from now. If my user wants to view last one year data on the chart from now what changes would my code require? NOTE:The demo here : https://www.highcharts.com/demo/stock/compare uses both the options. FYI- I am working with react-jsx-highstock library.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Then could you reproduce your issue in an online editor? You can use this demo as a template: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-gnev1?file=/demo.jsx